# Graphical equivalent to /dev/null?

Tags: xorg, gtk

I'm trying to run a GTK-based plotting library that I wrote over an SSH terminal that's too slow to run an X session over.  GTK assumes that a graphical display is present and won't work otherwise.  However, I only want to use this library to generate plots and save them to a file, not display them on the screen.  Is there any way I can set up a graphical equivalent to /dev/null as my graphical display, **without root access** to the machine in question?  Such a device would report sane values for resolution and depth (1280x1024, 24-bit, for example), and report that all screen drawing commands succeeded without doing anything, and make GTK think there was a real graphical display present.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb): "X virtual framebuffer is an X11 server that performs all graphical operations in memory, not showing any screen output."

***edit***  Whoops, I missed that bit about not having admin access (***edit*: it wasn't bolded then**).  Probably not an option then unless it's already set up.

Comment: Good answer anyways.  I have only ever heard of this being done using either xvfb or vnc / x11vnc.  There's not much you can do to change the basic configuration of the x server without any admin privileges.

Comment: It seems like, at least in theory, you could hook into ssh to present a dummy X display that would catch and discard the data that would normally go back through -X.  But I have about 0% of the considerable knowledge that would be necessary to estimate the practicality of such an endeavour.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use X.org's `dummy` video driver and `void` input driver. Using them will start a X server that does not connect to hardware and has little or no backing store. Pass `-config` to `Xorg` to use a separate config file you supply.

Comment: Can this be done w/o root access?

Comment: Provided the drivers are already in place, yes.

Comment: @dsimcha: on ubuntu look for package `xserver-xorg-driver-dummy`